# Prove that $f'(c)=(f(c)-f(a))/(c-a)$ isn't always correct

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I must find a function $f:[a,b]->R$ derived such that there is no c in $(a,b)$ for which:
$$f'(c)=(f(c)-f(a))/(c-a)$$

My professor said that $f(x)=x^3$ will work but I think that he is wrong, because $f'(-0.5)$ proves that the claim is correct and not the opposite.

can someone tell me who is wrong here and what example may work?

Comment: Just take a domain where the claim doesn't hold at all: The map $x\mapsto x^3$ from $(0,m)$ to $\Bbb R$ works where $m\gt 0$

Comment: so a=0 and b=1?

Comment: Sure, that works. We just need $2c^2\neq c^2+ac+a^2$, for $a=0$, this means we need $2c^2\neq c^2$, ie, $c^2\neq 0$, ie, $c\neq 0$, which would obviously be the case on $(0,1)$ (or just $(0,m)$ for $m\gt 0$) because $0\notin (0,m)$

Comment: $a=0$ and $b=1$ should work, notice that $f'(x)=3x^2$, while $$\frac{f(m)-f(0)}{m-0}=m^2$$ so the condition we get is $3m^2=m^2$ which is true for $m=0$ which can't happen in the domain we choose

Answer (score 1):

If we choose the interval $[a,b]=[0,1]$, suppose $\exists c\in(a,b)$ s.t. $$3c^2=\frac{c^3-0^3}{c-0}$$ This implies $c=0\notin(0,1)$, therefore we get a contradiction